# android - can't send or receive sms with android official sms app

Tags: sms

after i installed custom ROM on my phone(android 4.2.2), i rooted it and uninstalled hangouts(system app).

[i think] hangouts was default sms app 
after installing ROM .

now i **can't receive  sms** with **android official sms app**.
and when i send sms  , it **always stay on sending status**.

but i **haven't any problem with other sms apps**(go sms, hangouts[*after reinstall*],...)

I'm need to send or receive  sms with android official sms app.any ideas welcome.

P.S:

1.i installed new ROM for my 
phone locked on bootloop

2.i not found any difference between old ROM and new ROM.

3.i checked sms center number.

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i re-flashed my phone official ROM (without losing data by [this learn](http://www.gizbeat.com/7260/flash-rom-upgrade-firmware-without-losing-user-data-cache/)) and now this problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

Either stick to your other SMS app or try removing the default SMS app and reinstall it using an APK.